# How to convert this dynamic ajax function to vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have one jquery function for `ajax` and use for multiple process

```
<div id="status">
    <div id="waiting"></div>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div id="warning"></div>
    <div id="reject"></div>
</div>   

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {    
        getNotifStatus("waiting","datatable_1");
        getNotifStatus("success","datatable_2");
        getNotifStatus("warning","datatable_3");
        getNotifStatus("reject","datatable_4");
    });
    function getNotifStatus(val,select){    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '?val='+val+'&select='+select,
        success: function(data){
            $("#"+val).html("");
            $("#"+val).html(data);
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

in jquery i can use one function for many call with diffrent value but how use this in vue, i have try using vue but i think this only can use for call with same value in the same code and if i use vue i think this can by duplicating the function and reproducing the code with different value.

This vue code that i use.

```
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#status',
    data: {
      waiting: ''
    }
  })

  app.$http.get('https://example.org/?val=waiting&select=datatable_1')
    .then(function(response) {
      app.waiting= response;
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

</script>
```

whether it can use the same process with a dynamic jquery function?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a good thing?

Why should you keep your all requests in one place? This reduces the scalability of your application. You should keep them separated, to allow for adding/deleting of features.

But, if you must load them in one place, I suggest (given that you have split your 4 `<div>`s into components) that you use your ajax calls (all 4 at once) not in components, but in some common parent and then pass their response through properties.

But please keep in mind that it's an anti-pattern. If you wanted to make a good, robust application, you would keep each request in separate component.